# Rails API - Can't create user, password is FILTERED and return all validations errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I am trying to send a POST request in my API (to create an user), but I always get all password validations erros because my password came to API as FILTERED.

I didn't understand this errors because if I create an User from the console and try to login at my API (JWT authentication with email and password) the password is also FILTERED but everything works fine.

I want to keep password filtered.

My user create method:

```
# POST /users
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

My file filter_parameter_logging.rb:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [:password]
```

Curl command to create an User:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"email":"caio@email.com","password":"123456","name":"Caio A","age":"18"}' http://localhost:3000/users
```

Request response:

```
{"password":["can't be blank","Password is required","Password minimum size is 4 characters"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your curl command, you're not sending the params hash correctly.

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"user":
{"email":"caio@email.com","password":"123456","name":"Caio A","age":"18"}}' http://localhost:3000/users` or along those lines, according to your permitted strong params method `def user_params`